# My <ul> only displaying a bullet point for the first list item, not the rest

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my `<ul>` not displaying bullet points after the first list item.

```
<div id="links" class="info">
    <h6><strong>Useful links</strong> <img class="linkimage" src="link.png" border="0" /></h6>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p><a href="test.com" target="_blank">IT Services</a> </p>
            <p><a href="test.com" target="_blank">Human Resources</a> </p>
            <p><a href="test.com" target="_blank">Other</a> </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

No idea what I'm doing wrong, could someone please advise?

Comment: You only have one list item in that piece of code.

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/2f7mfu1j/ refer this

Comment: `<li>` = list-item, `<p>` = paragraph. A paragraph is not styled like a list-item.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Apologies, thought I could group it under one tag! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="links" class="info"> 
    <h6><strong>Useful links</strong> <img class="linkimage" src="link.png" border="0" /></h6>

      <ul>
        <li> 
          <a href="test.com" target="_blank">IT Services</a> 

</li>
<li>
  <a href="test.com" target="_blank">Human Resources</a> 
</li>
          
          <li>
          <a href="test.com" target="_blank">Other</a>

        </li>
      </ul>


  </div>
```

You have put only one `<li>`.

I have removed `p` tag, instead of having `p` you can give css to `ul` and `li` based on your needs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
<div id="links" class="info"> 
<h6><strong>Useful links</strong> <img class="linkimage" src="link.png" border="0" /></h6>

  <ul>
    <li> 
      <p><a href="test.com" target="_blank">IT Services</a> </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p><a href="test.com" target="_blank">Human Resources</a> </p>
     </li>
     <li>
      <p><a href="test.com" target="_blank">Other</a> </p>

    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```html
  <div id="links" class="info"> 
    <h6><strong>Useful links</strong> <img class="linkimage" src="link.png" border="0" /></h6>

      <ul>
        <li> 
          <p><a href="test.com" target="_blank">IT Services</a> </p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p><a href="test.com" target="_blank">Human Resources</a> </p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p><a href="test.com" target="_blank">Other</a> </p>
        </li>
        
      </ul>


  </div>
```

This should work

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="links" class="info"> 
    <h6><strong>Useful links</strong> <img class="linkimage" src="link.png" border="0" /></h6>

      <ul>
        <li> 
          <a href="test.com" target="_blank">IT Services</a> 

</li>
<li>
  <a href="test.com" target="_blank">Human Resources</a> 
</li>
          
          <li>
          <a href="test.com" target="_blank">Other</a>

        </li>
      </ul>


  </div>
```